# Unable to pass props when enum is used to define proptype

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-proptypes

I am using React + Typescript.

In one of my component I have declared the interface as

```
enum PersonDept {
   CIVIL = 'civil',
   PRIVATE = 'private'
}

interface IPerson {
   dept: PersonDept.CIVIL | PersonDept.PRIVATE
}
```

Now, If I've to use the person component anywhere else then I've to export the `enum` in order to pass `dept` prop type. Is there any way out there in which I can skip exporting the `enum`.

Also if I've to export the `enum` anyways, is the the right way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

According to your types, the property `dept` **accepts only the values** of the enum `PersonDept`.

So yes, you have to use the enum and import it on every usage, that's the desired behavior and how it usually used.

> Is there any way out there in which I can skip exporting the enum

One way is to not use the enum:

```
interface IPerson {
   dept: 'civil' | 'private'
}
```

And a more hacky and not recommended way is to set the enum as a global variable, like attaching it to `window`:

```
// Don't do it, just know it is possible
window._IPreson = PersonDept
```

Comment: thanks Dennis, yeah I can't go with hackish way. will go with the other one. i.e. exporting the enum.

Comment: Feel free upvoting if was helpful